# How can one modify PS1 to display time in right most corner?

Tags: shell, ps1

Currently it is displayed as follows

```
export PS1='${white}[\t] ${blue}\W:${red}$(__git_ps1)${white} \$ '
```

[image]

I'd like to experiment with the same set up, but time displayed in the right most corner.

How can i modify my `PS1` export for this to happen please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think there's any way to right justify items on the prompt using `PS1` in bash (pretty sure there's easy ways to do this in zsh though). You can try writing a function for the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable and have it print the time with right justify, something along the lines of:

```
print_pre_prompt ()
{
    TIME=`date +%H:%M`
    printf "\e[1;37m%$(($COLUMNS))s" "${TIME}"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=print_pre_prompt
```

Here, the `\e[1;37m` is the "white" color.

Comment: I thinks this limits time display on the current line?  If we want to display time in the bottom right corner, we will need the `save_cursor` and `restore_cursor` terminal features.

Comment: Any chance time can appear on the same line as the prompt?

Comment: @Jam If there it a way, it is beyond my bash-fu. I think even in zsh there's an issue of having it on the same line (the RPS1 built in) because your cursor will start overwriting it given long enough commands

Answer (score 1):

Is this your output prompt looking for ?

export PS1="\u@\w [\$(date +%k:%M:%S)]> "